# Twitter TypeAhead with Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, typeahead.js

Hi All can anyone provide me a good example of how to use Twitter Typeahead (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) in asp .net with database.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC you can create a controller action that returns JSON, like this:

view

```
@Html.TextBox("playerName")

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#playerName').typeahead({
            name: 'players',
            valueKey: 'playerName'  
            prefetch: '@Url.Action("AvaliablePlayers", "Player")',
            limit: 10
        });

    });

</script>
```

controller and action

```
public class PlayerController : Controller
{    
    public JsonResult AvaliablePlayers(int groupId)
    {
        var group = _groupRepository.GetById(groupId);


        return Json(group.Players.Select(p => new { playerId = p.PlayerID, playerName = p.Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And in ASP.NET WebForms you can use custom HTTP handler to return data in JSON format, like this:

Default.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox id="country" CssClass="countryTypeAhead" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.countryTypeAhead').typeahead({
            name: 'countries', 
            prefetch: '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Countries.ashx") %>',
            limit: 10
        });

    });

</script>
```

Add new `Generic Handler (.ashx)` named Countries to your project. Here is the Code-behind for the handler:

```
public class Countries : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            var cntries = new List<string>() {"Slovenia", "Italy", "Germany", "Austria"}; 

            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            context.Response.Write(jsSerializer.Serialize(cntries));

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This sample uses `JavaScriptSerializer` which is available in ASP.NET 3.5 and above. If you are using   asp.net of lover version than 3.5 you can use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to convert typeahead results to JSON format.

Comment: Default.aspx is missing a close quotation mark on the line that begins with "prefetch:"